Getting result of Earth Engine profiler as dict object
When working with Python and the Earth Engine API one could want to check the resource consumption of its computation. For that the Earth Engine API is shipped with a profiler that one can call like this:
import ee 

with ee.profilePrinting():
   ee.Number(3.14).add(0.00159).getInfo()

which provides the following result as a string output:

Is there a way to capture it and transform it to a dictionary object ?

geetools Profiler
I ended up implemented it directly into geetools, it can be called as such:
import ee, geetools 
with ee.geetools.Profiler() as p:
        ee.Number(3.14).add(0.00159).getInfo()
p.profile

{'EECU·s': [0.001, None],
 'PeakMem': [4720, 3100],
 'Count': [3, 3],
 'Description': ['(plumbing)', 'Algorithm Number.add']}


Manual implementation
First one need to create a io object to capture the output of the profiler
output_capture = io.StringIO()
with ee.profilePrinting(destination=output_capture):
    ee.Number(3.14).add(0.00159).getInfo()
captured_output = output_capture.getvalue()

Then you need to parse the resulting string to transform it into a dictionary:
def transform_to_dict(input_string):
    # Split the string into lines
    lines = input_string.strip().splitlines()

    # First line contains column headers
    headers = [h.strip() for h in lines[0].split()]

    # Initialize a dictionary to hold lists for each column
    result = {header: [] for header in headers}

    # Process each line of data after the header
    for line in lines[1:]:
        # Split the line by spaces, considering multiple spaces as a separator
        # Handle missing values denoted by "-"
        parts = [None if p == "-" else p for p in line.split()]

        # Populate the dictionary with values for each column
        result[headers[0]].append(float(parts[0]) if parts[0] is not None else None)  # EECU can be converted to float
        result[headers[1]].append(parts[1])  # Mem is a string (with "k" or other units)
        result[headers[2]].append(int(parts[2]))  # Count is an integer
        result[headers[3]].append(' '.join(parts[3:]))  # Description can have multiple words

    return result
dictionary = transform_to_dict(captured_output)

{'EECU·s': [0.001, None],
 'PeakMem': ['4720', '3.1k'],
 'Count': [3, 3],
 'Description': ['(plumbing)', 'Algorithm Number.add']}

